How to implement SSL pinning using public key in Ktor client
I am using the Ktor in my native application,

In which I will be receiving the Public key from the login API.
This public key I will be saving in a preference at init
Now I need to use this public key as part of Ktor client so that on each network call I will be validating the Key which will prevent Man in middle Attack as part of security

Hence I need to implement the SSL pinning as part of Ktor Client , Guide me on how to implement in native Android Application
My Ktor client look as below
val ktorHttpClient = HttpClient(Android) {
    expectSuccess = true
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(Json {
            prettyPrint = true
            isLenient = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            explicitNulls = false
        })
    }
}

In this I need to configure the SSL pinning via public key
SSL Manager Impl with engine in ktor, but the engine block is not executed confirmed with the log
val pin = "sha256/afwiKY3RxoMmLkuRW1l7QsPZTJPwDS2pdDROQjXw8ig="
    val PINNED_HOST_NAME = "qual.abc.com"
    engine {
        sslManager = { httpsURLConnection ->
            httpsURLConnection.hostnameVerifier = object : HostnameVerifier {
                override fun verify(hostname: String?, session: SSLSession?): Boolean {
                    // Check if the hostname matches the expected domain
                    if (!hostname.equals(PINNED_HOST_NAME, ignoreCase = true)) return false

                    // Extract the server's certificate chain
                    val certificates = session?.peerCertificates ?: return false

                    // Get the public key from the first certificate in the chain
                    val serverPublicKey = certificates[0].publicKey.encoded

                    // Convert the server's public key byte array to a hexadecimal string
                    val serverPublicKeyHex = Base64.encodeToString(serverPublicKey, Base64.NO_WRAP).toString()
                    Timber.tag("SSL pin").d("${pin.contentEquals(serverPublicKeyHex)}")
                    // Compare the server's public key with the pinned public key
                    return pin.contentEquals(serverPublicKeyHex)
                }
            }
            //  httpsURLConnection.sslSocketFactory = sslFactory.sslSocketFactory
        }
    }


I recommend reading https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-ssl to better understand how certificate pinning works on Android. On the Ktor side, you can use the sslManager method (https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-android/io.ktor.client.engine.android/-android-engine-config/ssl-manager.html) to configure the object of the HttpsURLConnection class. To solve the problem you can write your implementation of the HostnameVerifier class (https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#setHostnameVerifier(javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier))

Also, you can use the CertificatePinner class of the OkHttp client (https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html)

Okay @AlekseiTirman, but I have a case like I won't be needing the domain check, in my case just will be having the list of public keys which I need to check on each API call and how to attach to the ktor client, in my API call of ktor how can I check this request is valid

To what information about the server will the public key be pinned then?

I am asking is there a way of checking the certificate which holds public key, no matter what the domain

You can do it by using the sslManager method (https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-android/io.ktor.client.engine.android/-android-engine-config/ssl-manager.html), where you can call the connection.setHostnameVerifier method and use the second parameter session of the verify method of the HostnameVerifier object to get the peer certificates (session.peerCertificates). You can then check if at least one certificate's public key matches the downloaded one.

Based on your comment I used SSLManager and updated the code in the question, which is exactly the code in my app. I added the log in engine block is executed and not sure what's the reason.Can you check and let me know what's missed

Have you tried adding the log calls at the beginning of the verify method? Also, ensure the requests are made to the endpoint with the https scheme. Are you testing the code on an Android emulator or a physical device?

SSLManager works @AlekseiTirman, Thanks for the Help, the main issue was the Koin Injection, which I have added in the application due to lazy init of ktorClient there was issue
